# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool' working with GPIO pins

Tags: c#, gpio

I'm doing some work with my Raspberry Pi 3 and it's GPIO pins. I'm using a PDF file that is, unfortunately, coded in Arduino. I've tried looking up the conversion from Arduino to C# but could only find conversion form Arduino to native C. I got this code from it and it is compiling errors and I wanted to know why. I checked around Stack Overflow and couldn't find this anywhere so I asked it myself. (I've converted some of the code into code I use in c# like the top line. The rest I  have not touched.

```
void ShiftOut(GpioPin dataPin, GpioPin clockPin, bool MSBFIRST, byte command)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        bool output = false;
        if (MSBFIRST)
        {
            output = command & 0b10000000;
            command = command << 1;
        }
        else
        {
            output = command & 0b00000001;
            command = command >> 1;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: why is `output` a boolean?

Comment: why is `output` defined? It is not used!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# there is no implicit conversion between `bool` and `int`. In this line:

```
output = command & 0b10000000;
```

1. `command` is a `byte`
2. `0b10000000` is an `int`
3. `command & 0b1000000` returns an `int`.
4. `output` is a `bool`. There is no implicit (or explicit) conversion from `int` to `bool` so the assignment fails.

The question here is why is `output` declared as a `bool`?